# Displaying my own URDF

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried many different methods with no results and now I am asking this kind community.

I have created an URDF file in a package located inside catkin_ws
catkin_ws/src/farmbot_fyp/urdf/farmbot_urdf

and I would like to launch it in rviz, I have tried using the launch files from multiple sources but it did not work, HELP.
I will just want to launch it without depending on the urdf_tutorial display.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275451/displaying-my-own-urdf/) by [AllanXyl](https://answers.ros.org/users/32465/allanxyl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-09**:\

> I have tried using the launch files from multiple sources but it did not work

if you don't tell us what you've already tried - and if it didn't work, what happened instead - we *cannot* help you.

We're here to help, but *always include enough information*.

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-09**:
Try putting your display.launch here so we can give it a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, did you tried adding the robot model in the rviz window? You might be forgetting that.
It looks something like this:
[image: image description]

Click the button that says Add and then select Robot Model.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0